# How can I iterate over an array/object and add certain elements to an li?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object, html-lists

this is my first question so apologies if it's a little vague. I'm learning JS, and I've been stuck on a problem for several hours. I've been given an object, and told to add certain objects within that object to an ul.

```
{
"dsl": {  
"DSL-I-100000": {
    "DSL-I-100000": {      // Add this to an li  
        "priority": "1",  
            "standard": true,  
            "customer": true,  
            "internet": true,  
            "business": true,  
            "consumer": true,  
            "filename": "DSL-I-100000.json",  
            "download": "100",  
            "vpCategory": "dsli"  
    }
},  
"DSL-IP-100000": {  
    "DSL-IP-100000": {    // Add this to an li  
        "priority": "1",  
            "standard": true,
            "customer": true,
            "internet": true,
            "phone": true,
            "business": true,
            "consumer": true,
            "filename": "DSL-IP-100000.json",
            "download": "100",
            "vpCategory": "dslip"
    }
},  
"DSL-IP-16000": {    
    "DSL-IP-16000": {     // Add this to an li  
        "priority": "1",  
            "standard": true,
            "customer": true,
            "internet": true,
            "phone": true,
            "business": true,
            "consumer": true,
            "filename": "DSL-IP-16000.json",
            "download": "16",
            "vpCategory": "dslip"
    }
},
```

My task is to create a list containing the 'metacode' as my tutor put it. That would be '"DSL-I-100000":',"DSL-IP-100000":, "DSL-IP-16000":.  What's the best way to go about this? My JS knowledge is quite limited, so please do explain as though to a simpleton. Thank you in advance.

Comment: While typing, the object was properly formatted and easy to read, idk why it's not formatted now... sry guys

Comment: @iota fixed my formatting. Many thanks

Comment: can u please paste the expected output? I'm not sure I understand what it should be

Comment: Hi @Lior. Thanks for your attention :D My expected output would be 
*DSL-I-100000
*DSL-IP-100000
*DSL-IP-16000
The object I have is much bigger, I've only put the first three outputs here to give a general idea of what I need. Hence I cannot just target those three, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the keys from `obj.dsl` and for every key create a `li` element.

```js
const obj = {
  dsl: {
    "DSL-I-100000": {
      "DSL-I-100000": {
        priority: "1",
        standard: true,
        customer: true,
        internet: true,
        business: true,
        consumer: true,
        filename: "DSL-I-100000.json",
        download: "100",
        vpCategory: "dsli",
      },
    },
    "DSL-IP-100000": {
      "DSL-IP-100000": {
        priority: "1",
        standard: true,
        customer: true,
        internet: true,
        phone: true,
        business: true,
        consumer: true,
        filename: "DSL-IP-100000.json",
        download: "100",
        vpCategory: "dslip",
      },
    },
    "DSL-IP-16000": {
      "DSL-IP-16000": {
        priority: "1",
        standard: true,
        customer: true,
        internet: true,
        phone: true,
        business: true,
        consumer: true,
        filename: "DSL-IP-16000.json",
        download: "16",
        vpCategory: "dslip",
      },
    },
  },
};

const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

Object.keys(obj.dsl).forEach(k => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = k;
  ul.appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: @TraktorJack Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks Som! But the object I have goes on for quite a bit longer, I've only attached the first few nested objects. What I've tried so far is to convert the object into an array, because it seems easier to iterate over an array than an object. I was thinking that a for loop or function would be the most efficient solution?

Comment: @TraktorJack The solution that I gave is an efficient solution, even if there are many keys. `Object.keys()` indeed returns an array. If the structure of your object remains same, the no. of items wouldn't make this solution inefficient.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not expected to display every key. I've just commented at the top, I'm only expected to display the second last nested object, if that makes sense. Not every key

Comment: @TraktorJack Means if there are three keys you only want to display the second key? Please clarify so that I can help in a better way.

Comment: It worked. Can you explain how? I'm a little confused haha

Comment: @TraktorJack Where are you confused, if you can elaborate your problem, I would be able to help better.

Comment: I'm new to JS, and I don't quite understand how your code works. What is k? Are you able to explain it in 1-2 sentences? That would be awesome

Comment: `k` represents the keys in the object.

Comment: @TraktorJack Consider accepting it as an answer if it solved your problem. You can read more about accepting answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)